# OnePage Navbar detecting section IDs above target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with my [website](http://horizonstudio.hol.es)'s navigation bar.
It is supposed to detect and highlight the navigation link when the user has reached the Section ID. However, it seems to be detecting the section well above their target.

How would I get the navigation bar to accurately detect the sections?

Just in case, here's the jQuery smooth-scrolling code:

```
   ;(function($, window, document, undefined){

// our plugin constructor
var OnePageNav = function(elem, options){
    this.elem = elem;
    this.$elem = $(elem);
    this.options = options;
    this.metadata = this.$elem.data('plugin-options');
    this.$win = $(window);
    this.sections = {};
    this.didScroll = false;
    this.$doc = $(document);
    this.docHeight = this.$doc.height();
};

// the plugin prototype
OnePageNav.prototype = {
    defaults: {
        navItems: 'a',
        currentClass: 'current',
        changeHash: false,
        easing: 'swing',
        filter: '',
        scrollSpeed: 750,
        scrollThreshold: 0.5,
        begin: false,
        end: false,
        scrollChange: false
    },

    init: function() {
        // Introduce defaults that can be extended either
        // globally or using an object literal.
        this.config = $.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options, this.metadata);

        this.$nav = this.$elem.find(this.config.navItems);

        //Filter any links out of the nav
        if(this.config.filter !== '') {
            this.$nav = this.$nav.filter(this.config.filter);
        }

        //Handle clicks on the nav
        this.$nav.on('click.onePageNav', $.proxy(this.handleClick, this));

        //Get the section positions
        this.getPositions();

        //Handle scroll changes
        this.bindInterval();

        //Update the positions on resize too
        this.$win.on('resize.onePageNav', $.proxy(this.getPositions, this));

        return this;
    },

    adjustNav: function(self, $parent) {
        self.$elem.find('.' + self.config.currentClass).removeClass(self.config.currentClass);
        $parent.addClass(self.config.currentClass);
    },

    bindInterval: function() {
        var self = this;
        var docHeight;

        self.$win.on('scroll.onePageNav', function() {
            self.didScroll = true;
        });

        self.t = setInterval(function() {
            docHeight = self.$doc.height();

            //If it was scrolled
            if(self.didScroll) {
                self.didScroll = false;
                self.scrollChange();
            }

            //If the document height changes
            if(docHeight !== self.docHeight) {
                self.docHeight = docHeight;
                self.getPositions();
            }
        }, 250);
    },

    getHash: function($link) {
        return $link.attr('href').split('#')[1];
    },

    getPositions: function() {
        var self = this;
        var linkHref;
        var topPos;
        var $target;

        self.$nav.each(function() {
            linkHref = self.getHash($(this));
            $target = $('#' + linkHref);

            if($target.length) {
                topPos = $target.offset().top;
                self.sections[linkHref] = Math.round(topPos);
            }
        });
    },

    getSection: function(windowPos) {
        var returnValue = null;
        var windowHeight = Math.round(this.$win.height() * this.config.scrollThreshold);

        for(var section in this.sections) {
            if((this.sections[section] - windowHeight) < windowPos) {
                returnValue = section;
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    },

    handleClick: function(e) {
        var self = this;
        var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
        var $parent = $link.parent();
        var newLoc = '#' + self.getHash($link);

        if(!$parent.hasClass(self.config.currentClass)) {
            //Start callback
            if(self.config.begin) {
                self.config.begin();
            }

            //Change the highlighted nav item
            self.adjustNav(self, $parent);

            //Removing the auto-adjust on scroll
            self.unbindInterval();

            //Scroll to the correct position
            self.scrollTo(newLoc, function() {
                //Do we need to change the hash?
                if(self.config.changeHash) {
                    window.location.hash = newLoc;
                }

                //Add the auto-adjust on scroll back in
                self.bindInterval();

                //End callback
                if(self.config.end) {
                    self.config.end();
                }
            });
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    },

    scrollChange: function() {
        var windowTop = this.$win.scrollTop();
        var position = this.getSection(windowTop);
        var $parent;

        //If the position is set
        if(position !== null) {
            $parent = this.$elem.find('a[href$="#' + position + '"]').parent();

            //If it's not already the current section
            if(!$parent.hasClass(this.config.currentClass)) {
                //Change the highlighted nav item
                this.adjustNav(this, $parent);

                //If there is a scrollChange callback
                if(this.config.scrollChange) {
                    this.config.scrollChange($parent);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    scrollTo: function(target, callback) {
        var offset = $(target).offset().top;

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: offset
        }, this.config.scrollSpeed, this.config.easing, callback);
    },

    unbindInterval: function() {
        clearInterval(this.t);
        this.$win.unbind('scroll.onePageNav');
    }
};

OnePageNav.defaults = OnePageNav.prototype.defaults;

$.fn.onePageNav = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        new OnePageNav(this, options).init();
    });
};

})( jQuery, window , document );
```

Comment: It's working fine at my end here using Chrome 52, Firefox 47, IE11 and  Opera 38 on a Windows machine.

Comment: I mean your lower two sections are pretty short and as you did not provide us with your code, we cannot know what is e.g. your configured `scrollThreshold`. --- As soon as the section top or bottom reaches at about the center of the viewport, the respective navigation link is highlighted. (Your lower sections never reach that point.) If I add content using Firebug to those sections, it's working as expected.